# Blender 2.75 to 2.76 When adding an object I can't find the tool menu now!? Add (Vertices / Depth etc)

Tags: interface

Please see picture.. When I add an object there used to bne a place where i could adjust it before clicking off of it -- now that menu has gone somewhere and I can't find it. Am I missing something, I didn't turn on? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Click the `+` icon at the bottom of the region.
When the *redo menu* is resized to nothing, it is hidden and the `+` button for re-showing it appears:

[image]